# Remove unicode symbols from NSMutableString

Tags: swift, string, unicode

I have a generated String (contents of UITextView with image attachments) and need to save it to database

```
let textView = UITextView()
textView.text = "some text"
let attString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " ")
attString.replaceCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(0, 1), withAttributedString: NSAttributedString(attachment: NSTextAttachment()))
textView.textStorage.insertAttributedString(attString, atIndex: textView.text.length)
print("\(textView.text)")
```

Output: "some text". But if watch the content of textView.text via debugger, text contains "some text\u{ef}"

How to remove \u{ef} from textView.text and get "some text" inside textView.text?

```
textView.text = textView.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u{ef}", withString: "")
```

hasn't made expected effect

Current fix:

```
text = String(text.characters.filter() { $0 <= "~" })
```

Comment: How exactly is the string obtained and printed?

Comment: The string was from UITextView with image attributes
In XCode's debug mode when seeing on the string content it looks like "\u{ef}some text\u{ef}", but with print() it looks exactly as I want: "some text"

Comment: Please add *all* relevant information (including the print statement) to the *question,* not into the comments.

Comment: Martin, I reproduced the situation in small test and inserted code to the question's body

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the above code. (I can't even get the above code to compile; what version of iOS is this built for? `textView.text` returns `String`, which has no `length`. I think you meant `textView.attributedText.length`) The fact that your `print` statement behaves as expected suggests that you're having a problem in debugging. Do you have an example where actual program behavior is unexpected?

Comment: I haven't, I just don't want to store these symbols in database
Swift 2.4, IOS 10.0.2

Comment: It would be better to convert all the string to ASCII with removal of all unicodes. How it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

More definition is needed to really understand what you are trying to achieve and how those characters turn up in your string of interest.

If you really want to re-encode the string, potentially losing information such as multibyte characters, here's how you could encode it in latin1 (which, in the absence of detail about what encoding your database uses could well be the encoding you are after):

```
str.data(using: .isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: true)
```

(… or if you want to go completely caveman, `str.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: true)` – though again, your question is pretty unclear.)